# How to test for conditional independence with mix of categorical and continuous data

Tags: conditional-probability, multiple-comparisons, independence, mixed-type-data, anderson-darling-test

I wish to test for conditional independence between $X$ and $Y$ given $Z$. However $X$ is continuous, while $Y$ and $Z$ are categorical variables.

My idea is to test if $P(X|Z = z) = P(X|Y = y, Z = z)$ for all $y$ and $z$. One way I can think of doing this is to use a $k$-sample Anderson Darling test to test if $P(X|Z = z, Y = y)$ all have the same distribution, for a fixed $Z= z$ and taken over levels $Y=y$. Here $k$ would then be the number of levels in $Y$. This would involve multiple hypothesis tests, so should be corrected for this.

An issue with this is that I only have observations at some levels in $Z$, and at some levels in each $(Z,Y)$. Thus the $k$ in the $k$-sample AD test changes for each level $Z = z$. The total number of statistical tests that I perform then, and the number of samples used in each of these AD tests, is data dependent. My intuition tells me that not knowing how many tests are to be performed *a priori* is an issue for performing multiple testing corrections. But I'm not sure about this.

My questions, then, are:

1. For this approach in particular, is it OK to perform multiple hypothesis testing corrections based on $N$ hypotheses where $N$ is data dependent.
2. Are there other issues with the approach besides this multiple hypothesis testing/missing data concern?
3. More generally, is this a reasonable approach for testing for conditional independence between $X$ and $Y$ given $Z$, in this mixed data case, or is there a better way to go about this?